# Incrementing bit by bit in byte array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, counter, bit

I have a byte array of two bytes, which I'm using as a counter. I need to increment it bit by bit, as in:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0001
0000 0000 0000 0010
0000 0000 0000 0011
.
.
.
0000 0000 1111 1111
0000 0001 1111 1111
0000 0010 1111 1111
0000 0011 1111 1111
```

What's the cleanest way of doing this?

**EDIT**

Sorry for the super stupid question, I was looking at it the wrong way. Should anyone come across the same stupid question in the future: as mentioned in the comments, the easier way to do this is incrementing an Int16.

Comment: Please show a way you tried. Later be concerned about cleanest way

Comment: Use an Int16 - that already is a 2-byte value that can be incremented...If this doesn't work for you, please *edit your question* to explain why...

Comment: This is a classic [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are using the wrong tool for a simple job and ask us what's the best way to do it. Well, the best way is to use the right tool (Int16 as RB wrote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just convert the two bytes for Int16, append the bits you want, and then back to a byte array:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[2] { 10, 20 }; // your byte array
Int16 yourNumber = BitConverter.ToInt16(byteArray, 0); // converts your byte array to int16
yourNumber ++; // increments 1, which will do all the calculations for incrementing the bit(s) and handles overflow...
byte[] getBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(yourNumber); // converts the int16 to byte array (I think you should be using Int16, unless you really need to use a byte array)
```

I'm not sure what exactly you're requesting, if you just want to append a bit to a 2 byte array I think this is the fastest way to do it.